# Uncaught ReferenceError: mapboxgl is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, mapbox-gl

I am getting below(link) error message in console., I had spend hours try to fix this but won't be able to track this issue. Can someone help me to fix this?
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr7hQ.png)

I not able to display map on web page code is correct, but don't know what went wrong.
It would be great if anyone can explain in details with code. So that i can keep in mind and use for future  reference

Here is the code Main Code followed by Connected codes

```
//Pug Code
doctype html
html
  head 
    block head
      meta(charset='UTF-8')
      meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' value="script-src 'self' api.mapbox.com")
      link(rel='stylesheet' href ='/css/style.css')
      link(rel='shortcut icon' type='image/png' href='/img/favicon.png')
      link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,700')
      title Natours | #{title}

  body
    //HEADER
    include _header

    //CONTENT
    block content 
      h1 This is a placeholder heading

    //FOOTER
    include _footer

    script(src='/js/mapbox.js')
```

======================================================================================

```
Js code

/* eslint-disable */
const locations = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("map").dataset.locations);

mapboxgl.accessToken = 'xxxxxx';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style:'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',,
});
```

=================================================================================

```
//To display the map on  website below code is related to above code(this '==========' is only to show separate code from different file) //

  section.section-map
    #map(data-locations=`${JSON.stringify(tour.locations)}`)
```

Comment: You never declared the variable `mapboxgl` before trying to use `mapboxgl.accessToken`. Where is that supposed to come from?

Comment: @Barmar I believe it's from this.

```<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.14.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>```

Comment: Are you sure you're loading that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgot to add their library.

```
 head 
    block head
      meta(charset='UTF-8')
      meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' value="script-src 'self' api.mapbox.com")
      link(rel='stylesheet' href ='/css/style.css')
      link(rel='shortcut icon' type='image/png' href='/img/favicon.png')
      link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,700')
    
      //- add this line
      script(src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.14.1/mapbox-gl.js')
    
      title Natours | #{title}
```

Comment: That's the solution I was looking for , its working now .God Bless you!!!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming in the future, the solution is to simply disable the content security policy in **helmet**

```
app.use(helmet({
  contentSecurityPolicy: false
}))
```

then make sure that the default style used is the same as the one in the documentation at first and not some things that you've copied online.
So your `mapbox.js` should look like something like this:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'YOUR_TOKEN'
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'
});
```

Finally I removed the the script and css tags for the mapbox from the `tour.pug`, and added them in the `base.pug` with another meta tag

```
html
    head
        block head
            meta(charset='UTF-8')
            meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
            /* Add this */
            meta(http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' api.mapbox.com;worker-src blob: ;connect-src https://*.tiles.mapbox.com https://api.mapbox.com https://events.mapbox.com")
            /* */
            link(rel='shortcut icon' type='image/png' href='/img/favicon.png')
            link(rel='stylesheet' href='/css/style.css')
            link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,700')
            /* Add these 2 here */       
            script(src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.1/mapbox-gl.js')
            link(href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet') 
            /* */
            title Natours | #{title}

    body(data-alert=`${alert ? alert : ''}`)
  
        // HEADER
        include _header

        // CONTENT
        block content
          h1 This is a placeholder heading

        // FOOTER
        include _footer
        script(src='/js/mapbox.js')
```